# How to call onto the class that is in the tkinter mainloop?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been trying to call the class that is in my mainloop, but whenever I properly call it makes it that the program doesn't even launch anymore. I've been attempting to call it in order to get a method, which would return the current frame. I am aware that my code uses controller and parent to communicate between classes, but I haven't managed to fully grasp an understanding of these. If I call the mainlooped class, with "test = Database_project()", then the program won't run anymore. Can someone explain this to me? I'm trying to get the scrollbar feature to work on specific frames, and I haven't managed to figure out just yet. I'm trying to call the mainlooped class in the "CreatePage" class. Thank you in advance!

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

class Database_Project(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        
        stack_frame_container = tk.Frame(self)
        stack_frame_container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        stack_frame_container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        stack_frame_container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.frameslist = {}


        for frame in (MainPage, CreatePage):
            frame_occurrence = frame.__name__
            active_frame = frame(parent=stack_frame_container, controller=self)
            self.frameslist[frame_occurrence] = active_frame
            active_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="snew")

        #self.frameslist["CreatePage"].dbproject = self.frameslist["Datanase_Project"]

        self.current_frame("MainPage")
        print(self.frameslist)
            
    def current_frame(self, frame_occurrence):
        active_frame = self.frameslist[frame_occurrence]
        active_frame.tkraise()

    def get_current_frame(self, frame_occurrence):
        active_frame = self.frameslist[frame_occurrence]
        return active_frame

class MainPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        label_create = tk.Label(self, text="Create and insert data").grid(row=0, column=0, padx=50, pady=(50,0))
        create_button = tk.Button(self, text="CREATE", command=lambda: controller.current_frame("CreatePage")).grid(row=1, column=0)

        label_read = tk.Label(self, text="Query over data").grid(row=0, column=1, padx=50, pady=(50,0))
        read_button = tk.Button(self, text="READ").grid(row=1, column=1)

        label_update = tk.Label(self, text="Modify existing data").grid(row=2, column=0, padx=50, pady=(50,0))
        update_button = tk.Button(self, text="UPDATE").grid(row=3, column=0, pady=(0,50))

        label_delete = tk.Label(self, text="Remove data").grid(row=2, column=1, padx=50, pady=(50,0))
        delete_button = tk.Button(self, text="DELETE").grid(row=3, column=1, pady=(0,50))

class CreatePage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        self.inputlist = []
        self.newinputlist = []

        Test = Database_Project()
        #active_frame = Test.get_current_frame("CreatePage")
        #scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(active_frame, orient="vertical")
        #scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=2, stick="ns", columnspan=10)
        #text["yscrollcommand"] =

        labels = [tk.Label(self, text="Enter unique field"), tk.Label(self, text="Enter corresponding the value/s")]
        self.inputlist.append(labels[:])

        for toplabels in range(1):
            self.inputlist[toplabels][0].grid(row=toplabels, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)
            self.inputlist[toplabels][1].grid(row=toplabels, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)

        first_entries = [tk.Entry(self, borderwidth=5), tk.Text(self, borderwidth=5, height= 5, width=20)]
        self.newinputlist.append(first_entries[:])
        self.inputlist.append(first_entries[:])

        for x in range(0, len(self.newinputlist) + 1):
            self.newinputlist[0][x].grid(row=1, column=x, padx=10, pady=5)

        button_input_1 = [tk.Button(self, text="ADD FIELD/VALUE", command=self.add_insert), tk.Button(self, text="BACK", command=lambda: controller.current_frame("MainPage"))]
        self.inputlist.append(button_input_1[:])
        button_input_2 = [tk.Button(self, text="IMPORT FILE"), tk.Button(self, text="SUBMIT DATA", command=self.submit_data)]
        self.inputlist.append(button_input_2[:])
        
        for button in range(len(self.inputlist) - 2, len(self.inputlist)):
            self.inputlist[button][0].grid(row=button, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)
            self.inputlist[button][1].grid(row=button, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)

    def add_insert(self):

        add_input = [tk.Entry(self, borderwidth=5), tk.Text(self, borderwidth=5, height= 5, width=20)]
        self.inputlist.insert(-2, add_input)
        self.newinputlist.append(add_input)
        
        for widget in self.children.values():
            widget.grid_forget()

        for index, widgets in enumerate(self.inputlist):
            print(widgets)
            widget_one = widgets[0]
            widget_two = widgets[1]

            print(str(index), widget_one, widget_two)
            widget_one.grid(row=index, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)
            widget_two.grid(row=index, column=1, padx=10)

    def submit_data(self):
        for index, entries in enumerate(self.newinputlist):
            my_label = Label(self, text=str(entries[0].get()) + str(entries[1].get("1.0", END)))
            my_label.grid(row=len(self.inputlist) + index, column=0) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    NoSQL_Project = Database_Project()
    NoSQL_Project.title("NoSQL Database Project")
    NoSQL_Project.maxsize(500, 500)
    NoSQL_Project.mainloop()
```

Comment: well... remove this line: `Test = Database_Project()`, what even is it doing? there shouldn't be more than two instances of `Tk` anyways and the specific instance (`Test`) is not "mainlooped"

Comment: Yes I am aware of this, that's what I'm attempting to understand. The test is there because I want to called the method "get_current_frame". I understand it shouldn't be there, but I'm not sure how else I'm supposed to call the class. I left it in there because that's how I did it at the time, and the reason I'm asking for clarification

Comment: since `controller` is referencing instance that is "mainlooped" just use `self.controller.get_current_frame`, otherwise you are creating a new instance which you shouldn't do in this specific case

Comment: Yes, thank you that is what I was missing. I knew controller had something to do with it. Thanks for the clarification @Matiiss! I would claim your comment the correct solution, but not sure I can with a comment.

Comment: you can't, but not much of an issue, I can tho suggest that you maybe take a look at some OOP tutorials such as [this one by Corey Schafer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDa-Z5JzLYM&list=PL-osiE80TeTsqhIuOqKhwlXsIBIdSeYtc), for example, important thing would be that each time you do this (call class name): `ClassName()` (notice the parentheses) it creates a new instance of that class and it has its own place in memory, so for example in your code if you do `Test = Database_Project()` it creates a completely new window or sth because it is not related to `NoSQL_Project = Database_Project()`

Comment: I did look into because I do not usually do object oriented programming, this would be my first big project. But if its not too much to ask, when I use the '''self.controller.get_current_frame''' I get a keyerror on the frame called. Using lambda it does work, but I can't use that as a frame. Sorry to bother, but just got confused by this too

Comment: well, it depends on what argument you pass to that method, you should pass a key from the `self.frameslist` dictionary in `Database_Project`, so first try for yourself just printing out `print(self.controller.frameslist)` in the `CreatePage` class to know what keys there are, then call `self.controller.get_current_frame(key)` where `key` is a key from `self.controller.frameslist` dict

Comment: This is what I've been trying to run:
active_frame = self.controller.get_current_frame("CreatePage_InsertOne")
I know it exists because I have a separate instance where it calls it. But for some reason, doing it this way it only gives a keyerror

Comment: a keyerror means that the key does not exist, meaning that the dictionary (at least at the time of accessing with this key) doesn't have that key

Comment: "CreatePage_InsertOne" is not a valid key based on your code, but "CreatePage" is.

Comment: Huh, that would make sense. Interesting why it would do that. I'll try to look around and understand why it's registering it that way. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @acw1668 yes, I do know that. But that's because I've updated it and separated the createpage into three classes. So the "CreatePage_InsertOne" is included in the for loop for it to be added in the dictionary, and I have confirmed that it is by printing it.